# invalid date printed

Tags: javascript, mongodb, java-8, momentjs

I am using moment from mongorc.js (reference: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gabrielelana/mongodb-shell-extensions/master/released/mongorc.js) when executed this small snippet its printing "invalid date"

```
var text = "00000000000000"
var text1 = moment(text).format("MM/DD/YYYY, HH:mm")
print(text1)
moment(text,"YYYYMMDDHHmmss")
var text2=moment(text,"YYYYMMDDHHmm").format("MM/DD/YYYY, HH:mm");
print(text2)
```

But in Java:

```
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 public class DateTest {
public static void main(String[] s) throws Exception
{
    String a = "00000000000000";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");
    System.out.println(format.parse(a));
}}
```

Prints Sun Nov 30 00:00:00 IST 2

Though may not be correct, I want not "Invalid date" to be printed. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Since as you say yourself the date is not valid, what do you want printed instead? Just an idea, you could use an `if`-`else` statement.

Comment: In Java I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). They too will report that your date is invalid.

Comment: @OleV.V. the value should be default assigned to 01/01/0001 00:00:00, please lemme know how is it possible ?

Comment: Not knowing moment.js I would believe that it’s possible with a simple `if`-`else` statement (as I mentioned) (I only commented because I know that date was invalid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have hard coded the date value and it worked:

```
var text = "00000000000000"

if(RegExp(/^0*$/).test(text))
{
  text = "00010101000000" 
   moment(text,"YYYYMMDDHHmmss").format("MM/DD/YYYY, HH:mm"); 
 }
```